# Is there a way how to hide quick find on top of grid?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is there a way to hide quick find search box on top of grid - either programmatically or via ribbon / customizations ? Btw, it should be in supported/able manner (no direct DOM manipulations).

[image]

Comment: Is your answer under supported zone? I dont see anything covered for <dependencies> in docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/manifest-schema-reference/data-set

Comment: I even created a question, you can answer there - https://stackoverflow.com/q/64947343/7920473

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is interested - it is possible; it involves a shipping of your own custom grid control. Then in control manifest make sure to specify

`cds-data-set-options="displayViewSelector:false;displayQuickFind:false"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>
  <control namespace="MyControls.MyGridControl" constructor="MyGridControl" display-name-key="MyGridControl" description-key="MyGridControl" version="1.0.0" hidden="false" control-type="virtual">
    <modes><read /><edit /></modes>
    <data-set name="Grid" display-name-key="CC_Grid_DSGrid" cds-data-set-options="displayViewSelector:false;displayQuickFind:false"></data-set>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency name="MscrmControls.Grid.ReadOnlyGrid" />
    </dependencies>
    <resources>
      <code path="MyGridControl.js" order="1" />
    </resources>
    <AvailableOn>
      <web classic="enable" />
      <phone />
      <tablet />
    </AvailableOn>
  </control>
</manifest>
```

Comment: But this is a PCF control leveraging custom development right?

Comment: Yes - but that is not too hard / you can just wrap it to underlying MscrmControls.Grid.ReadOnlyGrid vanilla grid.

Comment: do you have the documentation url to do this, I have one requirement similar to this.. and have to add couple of extra search filters :)

Comment: not sure what Im doing wrong but getting error - Manifest validation problem: instance.manifest.control[0] is not allowed to have the additional property "dependencies"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately they are core platform functionalities and uncustomizable, and your necessity to turn off that capability is not an usual one. So it is not possible in any supported way today.

Maybe you can create an idea, if community voted for it - Microsoft may give that configuration in future releases.

Comment: Actually there is a way :)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I thought you were looking for Admin settings or something like that. my bad.